# php Session PHP getting data related to user

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Anyway im trying to connect my database so that it will only show information related to the user, but no matter where i look or see for this information, its either outdated or not relevant to me. 
Could i get some help on trying to confirm the confirmation

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
<t>
<p>Username: <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>

<?php endif ?>

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM `confirm`;";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) { 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['food'] , "<br>";
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: I forgot to add im trying to get the information related to the user but no matter what i add i keep getting errors

Comment: You might be missing a [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) call before trying to read the session.

Comment: the session_start is on another document, its reading the current user i already have in the system so thats not the issue

Comment: What are this errors you get? Add them in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of you want to fetch user specific information then you need to add a where clause in your sql query.
Something like

```
$name=$_SESSION[‘username’]; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `confirm` where name=‘$name’;";
```

Comment: it seems to be working correctly thanks but now that i fixed this issue what would be the best way to display the information

Comment: It depends according to the need. You can display in the form of a html list or a table. Also if my answer helped you mark it as accepted as it will let others know the problem is solved.